# How to reload hydra config with enumerations

Tags: pytorch, fb-hydra, omegaconf

Is there a better way to reload a hydra config from an experiment with enumerations? Right now I reload it like so:

```
initialize_config_dir(config_dir=exp_dir, ".hydra"), job_name=config_name)
cfg = compose(config_name, overrides=overrides)
print(cfg.enum)
>>> ENUM1
```

But ENUM1 is actually an enumeration that normally loads as

```
>>> <SomeEnumClass.ENUM1: 'enum1'>
```

I am able to fix this by adding a configstore default to the experiment hydra file:

```
defaults:
  - base_config_cs
```

Which now results in

```
initialize_config_dir(config_dir=exp_dir, ".hydra"), job_name=config_name)
cfg = compose(config_name, overrides=overrides)
print(cfg.enum)
>>> <SomeEnumClass.ENUM1: 'enum1'>
```

Is there a better way to do this without adding this? Or can I add the default in the python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question -- reliably reloading configs from previous Hydra runs is an area that could be improved.
As you've discovered, loading the saved file `config.yaml` directly results in an untyped DictConfig object.

The solution below involves a script called `reload.py` that creates a config node with a defaults list that loads both the schema `base_config_cs` and the saved file `config.yaml`.

At the end of this post I also give a simple solution that involves loading `.hydra/overrides.yaml` to re-run the config composition process.

---

Suppose you've run a Hydra job with the following setup:

```py
# app.py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum
import hydra
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStore
from omegaconf import DictConfig

class SomeEnumClass(Enum):
    ENUM1 = 1
    ENUM2 = 2

@dataclass
class Schema:
    enum: SomeEnumClass
    x: int = 123
    y: str = "abc"

def store_schema() -> None:
    cs = ConfigStore.instance()
    cs.store(name="base_config_cs", node=Schema)

@hydra.main(config_path=".", config_name="foo")
def app(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    print(cfg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    store_schema()
    app()
```

```yaml
# foo.yaml
defaults:
  - base_config_cs
  - _self_
enum: ENUM1
x: 456
```

```
$ python app.py y=xyz
{'enum': <SomeEnumClass.ENUM1: 1>, 'x': 456, 'y': 'xyz'}
```

After running `app.py`, there exists a directory `outputs/2022-02-05/06-42-42/.hydra` containing the saved file `config.yaml`.

As you correctly pointed out in your question, to reload the saved config you must merge the schema `base_config_cs` with the contents of `config.yaml`. Here is a pattern for accomplishing that:

```py
# reload.py
import os
from hydra import compose, initialize_config_dir
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStore
from app import store_schema

config_name = "config"
exp_dir = os.path.abspath("outputs/2022-02-05/07-19-56")
saved_cfg_dir = os.path.join(exp_dir, ".hydra")
assert os.path.exists(f"{saved_cfg_dir}/{config_name}.yaml")

store_schema()  # stores `base_config_cs`
cs = ConfigStore.instance()
cs.store(
    name="reload_conf",
    node={
        "defaults": [
            "base_config_cs",
            config_name,
        ]
    },
)

with initialize_config_dir(config_dir=saved_cfg_dir):
    cfg = compose("reload_conf")
print(cfg)
```

```
$ python reload.py
{'enum': <SomeEnumClass.ENUM1: 1>, 'x': 456, 'y': 'xyz'}
```

In the above, python file `reload.py`, we store a node called `reload_conf` in the ConfigStore. Storing `reload_conf` this way is equivalent to creating a file called `reload_conf.yaml` that is discoverable by Hydra on the config search path. This `reload_conf` node has a defaults list that loads both the schema `base_config_cs` and `config`. For this to work, the following two conditions must be met:

- the schema `base_config_cs` must be stored in the ConfigStore. This is accomplished by calling the `store_schema` function that we have imported from `app.py`.
- a config node with name specified by the variable `config_name`, i.e. `config.yaml` in this example, must be discoverable by Hydra (which is taken care of here by calling `initialize_config_dir`).

Note that in `foo.yaml` we have a defaults list `["base_config_cs", "_self_"]` that loads the schema `base_config_cs` before loading the contents `_self_` of `foo`. In order for `reload_conf` to reconstruct the app's config with the same merge order, `base_config_cs` should come before `config_name` in the defaults list belonging to `reload_conf`.

---

The above approach could be taken one step further by removing the defaults list from `foo.yaml` and using `cs.store` to ensure the same defaults list is used in both the app and the reloading script

```py
# app2.py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from enum import Enum
from typing import Any, List
import hydra
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStore
from omegaconf import MISSING, DictConfig

class SomeEnumClass(Enum):
    ENUM1 = 1
    ENUM2 = 2

@dataclass
class RootConfig:
    defaults: List[Any] = MISSING
    enum: SomeEnumClass = MISSING
    x: int = 123
    y: str = "abc"

def store_root_config(primary_config_name: str) -> None:
    cs = ConfigStore.instance()
    # defaults list defined here:
    cs.store(
        name="root_config", node=RootConfig(defaults=["_self_", primary_config_name])
    )

@hydra.main(config_path=".", config_name="root_config")
def app(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    print(cfg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    store_root_config("foo2")
    app()
```

```yaml
# foo2.yaml (note NO DEFAULTS LIST)
enum: ENUM1
x: 456
```

```
$ python app2.py hydra.job.chdir=false y=xyz
{'enum': <SomeEnumClass.ENUM1: 1>, 'x': 456, 'y': 'xyz'}
```

```py
# reload2.py
import os
from hydra import compose, initialize_config_dir
from hydra.core.config_store import ConfigStore
from app2 import store_root_config

config_name = "config"
exp_dir = os.path.abspath("outputs/2022-02-05/07-45-43")
saved_cfg_dir = os.path.join(exp_dir, ".hydra")
assert os.path.exists(f"{saved_cfg_dir}/{config_name}.yaml")

store_root_config("config")
with initialize_config_dir(config_dir=saved_cfg_dir):
    cfg = compose("root_config")
print(cfg)
```

```
$ python reload2.py
{'enum': <SomeEnumClass.ENUM1: 1>, 'x': 456, 'y': 'xyz'}
```

---

A simpler alternative approach is to use `.hydra/overrides.yaml` to recompose the app's configuration based on the overrides that were originally passed to Hydra:

```py
# reload3.py
import os
import yaml
from hydra import compose, initialize
from app import store_schema

config_name = "config"
exp_dir = os.path.abspath("outputs/2022-02-05/07-19-56")
saved_cfg_dir = os.path.join(exp_dir, ".hydra")
overrides_path = f"{saved_cfg_dir}/overrides.yaml"
assert os.path.exists(overrides_path)

overrides = yaml.unsafe_load(open(overrides_path, "r"))
print(f"{overrides=}")
store_schema()
with initialize(config_path="."):
    cfg = compose("foo", overrides=overrides)
print(cfg)
```

```
$ python reload3.py
overrides=['y=xyz']
{'enum': <SomeEnumClass.ENUM1: 1>, 'x': 456, 'y': 'xyz'}
```

This approach has its drawbacks: if your app's configuration involves some non-hermetic operation like querying a timestamp (e.g. via Hydra's [`now`](https://hydra.cc/docs/configure_hydra/intro/#resolvers-provided-by-hydra) resolver) or looking up an environment variable (e.g. via the [`oc.env`](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/custom_resolvers.html#oc-env) resolver), the configuration composed by `reload.py` might be different from the original version loaded in `app.py`.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer this is amazing!